# Slider verification failed on android simulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am using noxplayer emulator for Android app and I successfully installed the apk in my emulator. My emulator system is Android 7(64bit) and my host machine is Windows 11.

I could open that app in the emulator and it works fine. The problem is when I want to log in, it will prompts a slider verification for security checking and the verification fails even if I do the sliding with my mouse or with the auto sliding by the simulator. I can't do anything without logging in.

I'm not familiar with Andriod developing. Has anyone studied this issue before? What's the possible solution?